# How to change synthesized speech voice language UWP?

Tags: c#, linq, text-to-speech

I would like to change text to speech voice langauge.
This is my code:

```c#
private async void readText(string text)
{
    var voices = SpeechSynthesizer.AllVoices;
    SpeechSynthesizer speech = new SpeechSynthesizer();
    speech.Voice = voices.First(x => x.Gender == VoiceGender.Female && x.Language.Contains("fr-FR"));
    SpeechSynthesisStream stream = await speech.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(text);
    mediaElement.SetSource(stream, stream.ContentType);
}

private void btnSay_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    readText(txtWhat.Text);
}
```

But when I try to run this code, there is exception thrown in line:

```
speech.Voice = voices.First(x => x.Gender == VoiceGender.Female && x.Language.Contains("fr-FR"));
```

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Linq.dll but was not handled in user code.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Try FirstOrDefault. Are you sure that french language is installed?
I have using  
 speech.Voice = (from voice in Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesizer.AllVoices
                           where voice.Language == "fr-FR"
                           select voice).First();

Comment: Do you have microphone in manifest capabilities?
<Capabilities>
  <DeviceCapability Name="microphone" />
</Capabilities>

Comment: I haven't installed french language, how can I do that?

Comment: The error you are seeing is because your sequence contains no elements on your first call.  Using FirstorDefault will return Null if there are no values in which you could perform a null check on to make sure to proceed if you need to.  If its null on the language you need then its likely not installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check is your application has microphone access grants (in manifest)

```
<Capabilities> 
<DeviceCapability Name="microphone" /> 
</Capabilities>
```

Frome code you can check it with:

```
bool permissionGained = await AudioCapturePermissions.RequestMicrophonePermission();
if (!permissionGained)
{
//ask user to modify settings
}
```

And better check first is language installed in system:

```
var list = from a in SpeechSynthesizer.AllVoices
       where a.Language.Contains("en")
       select a;

if (list.Count() > 0)
{
synthesizer.Voice = list.Last();
}
```

Comment: I checked what languages I have installed:
            foreach (var voice in SpeechSynthesizer.AllVoices)
            {
                txtVoices.Text = voice.Language;
            }
It seems I don't have french language. TextBox shows me only one langugage.

Comment: Here is article how to install language and set it for speech recognition
[Installing additional language packs for Windows 10 speech recognition](https://zulja.wordpress.com/2015/08/11/installing-additional-language-packs-for-windows-10-speech-recognition/)

Comment: Thank you, I installed language and now It works with my original code.

I have one more question, Is it possible to change pitch, volume or speed using SpeechSynthesizer? How can I do that?